How can I define precompiler constants across projects?
I have a project structure consisting of the following projects:

Core (library)
MAUI (.net 8 Maui)
Web (.net 8 Blazor Server)

The MAUI and Web projects have a reference to the Core project.
Core contains, among other things, the models.
One of these models should make use of the "EntityTableData" repository.
However, this should only be the case if the Web project is compiled. The Maui project should not be able to use this repository.
I have added the line <DefineConstants>WEBAPP</DefineConstants> to the csproj of the "Web" project.
Then I extended my model as follows:
public abstract class AbstractBaseModel
#if WEBAPP
        : EntityTableData
#endif
    {
     .....
    }


Unfortunately, the reference is not taken into account when compiling.

And AbstractBaseModel is defined in the  the "Web" project?

@lidqy Sorry, this information was missing.
No AbstractBaseModel is not defined in Web but directly in Core.

I'd expect web project related compiler stuff to be only there. Otherwise you need to compile core for each project individually, which you can also do.

Maybe a better way to organize this: have 2 solutions (one for desktop and one for web), each uses core library and its own configuration. What brings packing everything in one solution precisely? Ideally you want to have core library as git-submodule, then changes to library have to be followed by individual commits for desktop and web project, which is good.
